# New delimited shapefile for Delhi

Tags: data-request, geospatial

I was looking for a shapefile of Delhi (ward-wise) updated after the delimitation of its 272 wards this year.

I got the old shape file based on delimitation in 2007 [here](https://groups.google.com/group/datameet/attach/4e31ba05492f49e1/Delhiwardsdelimited.zip?part=0.1&authuser=0).

I have individual images of all the new wards [here](http://www.delhi.gov.in/wps/wcm/connect/doit_dsec/Delhi+State+Election+Commission/Home/Delimitation+2016/) (last 3 items in the list on left), but I need a complete updated ward-wise map of Delhi.

Comment: You can always hackily convert a raster image to a shapefile.